# Python string, using finding specific word then copy the word and pasting it

Tags: python, nlp, information-retrieval

hey guys so i have this txt files which is like the following:

```
parent text \n -reply to first text\n --reply to second text
```

now what i want is that something like the following:

```
parent text\n - reply to parent text\n
-reply to parent text \n -- reply to second text\n
```

i know i can do this in python:

```
group = re.findall(r"--",data)
```

which will get all the -- without the text following it but since i have multiple "-" in each text this make me confuse on how to process the data any kind of insight ?

edit1:
This is my data

```
Why can\'t I find a girlfriend?\n-/u/remainenthroned \n-try tinder\n--r/incels\n--Maybe you should find a TreeHugger.\n---Got friendzoned there once, so nah\n----Trees are not so good with motion, you know.\n-----try grindr\n
```

which after .split \n is like :

```
"Why can't I find a girlfriend?",
 '-/u/remainenthroned ',
 '-try tinder',
 '--r/incels',
 '--Maybe you should find a TreeHugger.',
 '---Got friendzoned there once, so nah',
 '----Trees are not so good with motion, you know.',
 '-----try grindr',
```

what i would want is :

```
"Why can't I find a girlfriend?" -/u/remainenthroned,
"Why can't I find a girlfriend?" -try tinder'
-/u/remainenthroned --r/incels',',
```

so on and so forth

Comment: You should post your code and show the results. It's not terribly clear from your description what transforms you want to do on the data. For example, there are some whitespace differences. I can't tell if this is intentional.

Comment: edited sorry for being unclear, do tell if there's need to be more clarification :)

Comment: It appears that you're asking for some tutorial in program design; this is a bit beyond Stack Overflow's purpose.  This isn't a simple "split" problem: you have a data hierarchy whose parent-child relationships are indicated by how many hyphens preceded each statement, much like Python code indentation.  "Any insight?" is a strong hint that you need half an hour or so with a local tutor, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Prune i'm very sorry then, i don't know if it's actually more than the scope of stack overflow. Cause i'm not that familiar with the stack overflow scope. If its possible to remove/lock the thread, admin then please do so

Comment: @user3646742: don't worry about it; this is mainly crowd-sourced moderation.  I'm trying to guide you toward an effective, long-term solution.  You have a valid answer below for part of the problem, and we don't yet have a quorum voting to close your question.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0):

**if your data is in a file**
assuming that the file name is `text.txt`

```
with open("text.txt",'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()
    "\n".join(txt.replace("\n"," ").split("--")
```

**If your data is in a variable:**
assuming your variable is `text`

```
result = "\n".join(text.replace("\n"," ").split("--"))
```